# How to navigate using Tab Bars in Swift using Xibs

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I am trying to use a tabbar to navigate to other view controllers using Xibs. However, I am not able to find tangible resources to proceed further. My current solution involves mapping and I cannot seem to see where the problem is.

```
import UIKit

class BottomNavViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var home: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var assets: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var transactions: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var profile: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigateTab()
    }

    func navigateTab() -> Void{

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        let homeVC = HomeViewController()
        let assetsVC = AssetsViewController()
        let transactionsVC = TransactionsViewController()
        let profileVC = ProfileViewController()

        let controllers = [homeVC, assetsVC, transactionsVC, profileVC]

        tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers.map {
            UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply it is like this, You want use **UITabbarController**

```
class MYTabViewController: UITabBarController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let firstVC = FirstVC()
        firstVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab 1", image:(your image), tag: 0)

        let secondVC = SecondVC()
        secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab 2", image: (your image), tag: 1)

        viewControllers = [firstVC,secondVC]
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting an `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'tag:', expected 'coder:')` @Dilan

Comment: @KevinKibet, please add what  are you doing to fix it.because it will help someone.

Comment: your solution is the one that worked..i had just forgotten to add the image